# Stuck in bootloop Neffos X1. No recovery mode

Tags: boot-loop

My phone (Neffos X1) is stuck in a bootloop since yesterday evening. I haven't done any updates (at least not manually) or new installations recently, so it just happened out of the blue. It loads till the Neffos logo and then restarts over and over again.

Since I can't take the battery out, I tried letting it run out of energy and then restart, but as soon as I connect it to a power source the bootloop will start again.

My Phone won't react to any button combination, so I also can't access recovery mode, or any other mode by that matter.
I tried flashing it via SP Flash Tools, but the phone doesn't react to it.

My laptop actually doesn't seem to detect my phone at all, so I can't use ADB as well, can't unlock bootloader or get into fastboot. At least I don't know how.
I tried removing my SD card, since that seems to be the problem sometimes, but it also didn't help.

Is there anything I can do to get out of the bootloot or is it beyond fixing? Like I said, it just happened out of the blue, so it would be pretty upsetting, if my phone just broke for no reason.

I would appreciate any help very very much, so thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On every android I've had holding down the power button 30-90 second will hard power the phone off. you should be able to enter the bootloader by holding the entry button combination and letting it bootloop

Answer (score 0):

2 cents' worth :

Had the exact same thing on a Neffos X1 Lite today (9-29-20).
Phone was offline (no wifi, no phone network), and ringing out on alarm clock, when I hit snooze, and then it started looping like crazy (15-20 min until resolved) - Of course I've no idea if these conditions had anything to do with it.

While looping, I took out sim and memory card.
I hit power+Vol.Down, for a what seemed like eternity -
This didn't seem to stop re-booting, but then at one point, out of the blue, boot screen appeared for a split second, and one of the choices on the menu was picked up (either by me when already pressed keys leaped into it, or by system..?) - The phone restarted back to normal at that point. phewww.